# cocoa: How to know if another application grabbed the mouse

Tags: macos, cocoa, events, notifications, mouse

I ve been searching for this, but I cant find the answer anywhere. :-(

**How can I check if another application grabbed the mouse input for exclusive access?**
Is there some kind of notification or event for this?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by “grabbed the mouse input for exclusive access”?

Comment: It is when some other application "captures" all the mouse events and dont let any other receive them. It is very common in some games when windowed, see minecraft. You can also see this in effect in Virtual Machines like Virtual Box or Parallel desktop (without seamless modes).